# Change bootable USB stick

Tags: dual-boot, usb, mac

I'm brand new here and have been using Ubuntu on my Mac via two USB sticks for a few days. Today the first problem happened. My Mac wouldn't turn on anymore, which I never had before but now everything is fixed.
But I think it could be that the usb stick that starts Ubuntu (which I booted and copied the installation file to it) is very old,  it is USB 2 and at least 6 years old.
Now I wanted to put everything on a new USB stick to prevent this from happening again. How can I copy the existing one to the new one without losing the settings I already made?

I hope my question is not so trivial but I'm just starting to get into it.

Many greetings,
Naike

Comment: If you have a USB stick with Ubuntu Live on it, boot Ubuntu Live, insert the old USB stick and use Disks to create an image of it. Boot the old USB and use Disks to restore the image to the new stick. This will clone the complete old USB including the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to clone a bootable device that *isn't* running to ensure the data is "clean".

If your computer still has macOS (or OS X) installed on the internal storage, you should be able to use the "Disk Utility" software. Connect both USB drives to your Mac. Then do the following.

1. Click on the Restore tab
2. Drag the source USB drive over to where it says Source
3. Drag the destination USB drive over to where it says Destination
4. Click the Restore button

Make sure the new USB stick is the same size or larger than the source, and you should be good to go.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Ok, that sound easy. Thanks a lot!
I prepared the source USB via Windows because no software for the booting worked on my Mac. I used rufus to put ubuntu bootable on the USB stick. Did I have to prepare the new USB stick before your procedure? 

Greetings, Naike